# Swift 4 - Accessing Generic Json Object for Codable Struct

Tags: json, swift, parsing, swift4

My APIs always return a Json with the following structure:

```
{
    "data": Object
}
```

Where "Object" can be a primitive data (ex. String), another Json object or a Json array.

```
{
    "data": "string"
}

{
    "data": {
       "id_user": 1
       "name": "name"
    }
}

{
    "data": [{
       "id_user": 1
       "name": "name"
    },
    {
       "id_user": 2
       "name": "name"
    }]
}
```

How can I access to "Object" so that I can parse it using Codable structs?

Comment: The more flexible, the more code has to be written. Write a custom initializer in the enclosing struct which handles the cases.

Comment: @vadian how? Which types could I use for the Object variable?

Comment: If the `id_user / name` struct is always the same create a `Decodable` struct (e.g.`User`) and the cases are `String`, `User` and `[User]` for key `data`.

Comment: I can't do that because I can have a lot of possible structs, that's why i need a generic type to access "data" content and then parse it using JSONDecoder

Comment: The generic behavior of `Encodable` / `Decodable` is only related to the concrete types it supports. You cannot decode a generic type which is not derived from one of the supported generic types

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out a solution, using Dictionary. In this way I can access the "data" content, cast it to Data and then parse it with Codable. Here's the code:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: []) as! [String: Any]
guard let dataKey = json["data"] else {
    throw CustomError.dataNotFound
}
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dataKey, options: [])
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(CodableStruct.self, from: jsonData)
```

Hope it helps.